# print receipt with dynamic height by printDocument C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Iam using Visual Studio 2012 to build and printer: EPSON TM-T88IV Receipt to print.
I created a printDocument and here is my code:

```
public void print_ticket(string service){

    int pos = Array.IndexOf(x_service_print_key, service);

    // Nếu phím bấm tồn tại để kích hoạt in phiếu
    if (pos > -1)
    {
        string printer_code = "1";
        string service_code = x_service_code[pos];
        string priority = x_priority[pos];
        string number = (Convert.ToInt32(x_serial_number[pos]) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(x_serial_number[pos].Length, '0');

        // Lấy số cuối cùng của dịch vụ cộng thêm 1 và gán cho biến number
        string sql = "SELECT number FROM current WHERE service_code = '"+x_service_code[pos]+"' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
        DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                number = (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("number"))) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(x_serial_number[pos].Length, '0');
            }
        }
        reader.Close();

        // Insert vào database số mới.
        sql = "INSERT INTO current(printer_code, service_code, priority, number) VALUES('" + printer_code + "','" + service_code + "'," + priority + ",'" + number + "')";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Cập nhật ra màn hình
        this.Controls.Find("lbl_" + x_service_code[pos].ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault().Text = number;


        // In phiếu ra giấy
        printTicket.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            // Khai báo thông số text
            // -- Màu sắc
            SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            // -- Font chữ, size chữ
            Font drawFont1 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            Font drawFont2 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 60, FontStyle.Bold);
            Font drawFont3 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
            Font drawFont4 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold);
            // -- Căn giữa
            StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
            drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            // Logo
            Image imgLogo = QMSBUTTON.Properties.Resources.p_logo;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgLogo, 20, 0, 280, 24);
            // Khoa khám bệnh
            RectangleF recAtZero = new RectangleF(0, 25, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("KHOA KHÁM BỆNH", drawFont1, drawBrush, recAtZero, drawFormat);
            // Số thứ tự
            recAtZero = new RectangleF(0, 50, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(number, drawFont2, drawBrush, recAtZero, drawFormat);
            // Tên dịch vụ
            recAtZero = new RectangleF(0, 150, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(x_service_name[pos], drawFont3, drawBrush, recAtZero, drawFormat);
            // Phiếu in lúc
            recAtZero = new RectangleF(0, 180, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Phiếu in lúc: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss - dd/MM/yyyy"), drawFont1, drawBrush, recAtZero, drawFormat);
            // Phiếu chỉ có giá trị trong ngày!
            recAtZero = new RectangleF(0, 200, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Phiếu chỉ có giá trị trong ngày!", drawFont4, drawBrush, recAtZero, drawFormat);


        };

        printTicketDialog.ShowDialog();
        //printTicket.Print();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I print, the height of page is so long and didn't cut right after finish document. I need it cut dynamic after the last drawing text.

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the way:

```
PaperSize pageSize = new PaperSize();
pageSize.Width = 284;
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pageSize;
```

Set papeSize to printDocument, but only set Width, **don't set Height**. The printDialog will look strange but printer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add list of supported paper sizes found on the printer. 
// The DisplayMember property is used to identify the property that will provide the display string.
comboPaperSize.DisplayMember = "PaperName";

PaperSize pkSize;
for (int i = 0; i < printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; i++){
    pkSize = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i];
    comboPaperSize.Items.Add(pkSize);
}

// Create a PaperSize and specify the custom paper size through the constructor and add to combobox.
PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 100, 200);

comboPaperSize.Items.Add(pkCustomSize1);
```

link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.papersizes(v=vs.110).aspx